# Inputstream delivers unexpected message

Tags: android, inputstream

I'm trying to write an Android Application to send and recieve serial messages.
Everything works without any errors, but my InputStream delivers strange messages only.
They always look like: "B@410d2530" or "B@410a5f58". So it seems something hexa is counting, tho im not even sending something to my android device I dont know what this messages could be.
Even if im sending serial messages to my device via hterm these are just getting ignored and its just showing the "B@xxxxxxx" messages

```
    InputStream in = new InputStream() {

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return 0;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int byteshelp = 0;
String bla;
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in, BUFFER_SIZE);
private void readData() {
    byte[] bufferhelp = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try {

        byteshelp = bis.read(bufferhelp, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

        bao.write(bufferhelp, 0, byteshelp);
        byte temp[] = bao.toByteArray();
        Log.v("BLA", "Thats in Temp: " + temp);

        bao.reset();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Im using Android NDK and my InputStream is connected to a FileInputStream to handle data with the SerialPort.
The read method is threaded, so it delivers data nonstop.

So my main question: Anyone knows what this "B@410d2530" messages could mean?

Id be very happy to get an answer and feedback to my questioning, since im still new to the stackoverflow-community.

Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Log.v("BLA", "Thats in Temp: " + temp);
```

When u Log a byte array object, by default `Object` class `toString()` method will be called to convert it to a string.

The `toString()` method returns a String i.e., ObjectClassName@HashCode.

Here in **B@410d2530**, **B** - byte, **@** - character and **410d2530** - hasCode of that particular instance.

**Solution :**

If you want to convert your `byte[]` to `String`, You can use the [String(byte[] bytes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor for that. i.e.,

```
String s = new String(temp);
Log.v("BLA", "Thats in Temp: " + s);
```

Comment: ok, now ive tried to straight deliver temp to my android textview showing the content of temp instead of using tostring. its still showing the hashcode. so what i want to achieve is getting the input i get straight to an output on my textview.

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.v("BLA", "Thats in Temp: " + temp);
```

`temp` is an array, and you are calling `toString()` method in `Object` class.

```
public String toString() {
     return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

You can see official doc.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()